# Django: Import from project root

Tags: django, import, external, root

I was searching for an answer but could not get the solution for this exact case:

So, my project structure is like this

```
project/
    myproject/
        ...
    app/
        ...
        views.py
        ...
    logic/
        do_stuff.py    
    db.sqlite3
    manage.py
```

And this `do_stuff.py` contains a function `call_me()`

How can I call `call_me()` function from `views.py` (For example, upon a successful file upload)?

Many thanks!

Update:
I'm able to import a `do_stuff()` function from a single `logic.py` file from `project/` like this: `from .logic import do_stuff`

But the problem is that the logic package is already written and has its folder structure.

I just thought of installing this package via `settings.py`, is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Normally `from project.logic.do_stuff import call_me` should work in `views.py`. Have you tried?